# Use of 空降兵 in net language

Tags: meaning-in-context, mandarin

This particular word has been a sore spot for me.
空降兵
I know it literally translates as Paratroopers. like Air raiders or smth.
but I heard its also an internet slang.
Id love to know what it means.

Answer (score 4):

"空降兵" and its related words are mainly used in the [Danmaku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danmaku_subtitling) of video websites.

When watching a video, the behavior of dragging the progress bar to skip the video content is called **"空降"**

Successfully dragging the progress bar to the desired position is called **"空降成功"**

Danmaku or video content that includes fast-forward time points is called **"空指部"** or **"指挥部"**

The behavior of ignoring the fast-forward time point information and directly fast-forwarding is called **"盲降"**

Here are some examples of related Danmaku content

**“盲降成功，反手炸了指挥部”**

Success fast-forwards without taking advantage of information shared by others

**“空降成功，感谢指挥部”**

Use information shared by others to fast-forward success

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: what do you mean with [barrage](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/barrage)? Also, about your examples, without any context they are very hard to understand.

Comment: Thanks for your question, I have fixed them